# Error in WCF for my web service

Tags: c#, wcf

> ### Server Error in '/LogCollection' Application.
>
> The type 'LogCollection.LogCollection', provided as the Service
>   attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the
>   configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The type
>   'LogCollection.LogCollection', provided as the Service attribute value
>   in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The type 'LogCollection.LogCollection',
>   provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive,
>   or provided in the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.]
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +59766
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1434
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo
>   serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The service
>   '/LogCollection/LogCollection.svc' cannot be activated due to an
>   exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The type
>   'LogCollection.LogCollection', provided as the Service attribute value
>   in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found..]    System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
>   +499660    System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +178
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +350830
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +9668129

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18213

Why i am getting this error?
My Config file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="LogCollection.Settings1" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <applicationSettings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />

    </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />          
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  />

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: _"The type '`LogCollection.LogCollection` was not found"_. Make sure you configure the full name of your service implementation.

Comment: Where to configure? Can u tell me exactly wht to do?

Comment: Got it, In the mark up file both the namespace and class name are same. Thanks